Is "relative risk time" meaningful? (transient relative risk)
Context:
I'm trying to specify a data-generating / mechanistic model for a simulation study. I assume that exposure $e$ (a short event) has a transient effect on the relative rate of another process $k$. I define this effect as:
$$RR_{e:k}(t-t_e) = 1 + \beta\exp(-(t-t_e)/\tau)$$
where:
$t$ is the current time;
$t_e$ is the time of event $e$;
$\beta$ controls the strength of effect; and
$\tau$ controls the duration.
Intuitively, the cumulative effect of a single exposure $e$ is proportional to both $\beta$ and $\tau$, and the area under the curve $(RR-1) = \beta\tau$, mathematically.
Question:
Is this area under the $(RR(t)-1)$ curve useful to interpret as some measure of "relative risk time", without considering the base rate of $k$? Is there a better term to describe this quantity?
